# How to Use "InsertRow" in VBA for a Range of Cells (Excel 2013)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA & hoping someone can assist - I searched for this specific issue but I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to write a Module (using MS Office Professional Excel 2013) that will Insert Rows based on the Integer in Column "O" of each row.

I was able to get this working for one row by hard coding the cell:

```
Sub InsertRow()
Set currentcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2")
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, m As Long
    n = currentcell.Value
    m = currentcell.Row
    For i = 1 To n
        Rows(m + 1 * i).Insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

What I'd now like to do is create a Loop that will perform this action for the entire sheet. Here's what I have right now:

```
Sub InsertRow()
Set currentcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:O400")
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, m As Long
    n = currentcell.Value
    m = currentcell.Row
    For i = 1 To n
        Rows(m + 1 * i).Insert
    Next i
    Loop
End Sub
```

This currently returns `Compile Error: Loop Without Do.`

Any help, resources, suggestions for this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Liz

Comment: You don't need the `loop` if you're doing `for`.

Comment: You've got `loop` there which is the end of a `do` loop not a `for`. Also you don't seem to be incrementing `m` in your loop. Not sure if this is intentional or not

Comment: Comment here so we don't keep hitting Tom. So set `currentcell` to just one cell within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `loop` from your code. It is the syntax for the end of a `Do` loop not a `for` loop

```
Sub InsertRow()
Set currentcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:O400")
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, m As Long
    n = currentcell.Value
    m = currentcell.Row
    For i = 1 To n
        Rows(m + 1 * i).Insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Update:**
After comments to show looping through the range instead

```
Sub InsertRow()
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim i as integer, n as integer, m as integer

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:0400")

    For Each c in rng
        i = c.value
        m = c.row
        Rows(m + 1 * i).Insert
    Next c
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! That makes sense. Now am receiving the error "Type mismatch" in reference to the line: "n = currentcell.Value"

Comment: What is the current value? If it does not contain an integer it will throw the error. Perhaps change your declaration of n to `variant` if the cell won't always contain an integer.

Comment: Thank you Tom! This is my first post here so I apologize for the lack of formatting in the original post. The value is an integer and I am getting the error with both "Variant" and "Integer." I will search for this specific problem before I take up any more of you time.

Comment: @Liz the variable currently holds `Range("O2:O400")`. You can only grab `value` from a single cell.

Comment: Thank you @findwindow - is there an alternative to "Value" I can use that will allow me to pull from multiple cells?

Comment: Why do you want to pull from multiple cells? You want to check one by one yes?

Comment: Yes - I want to repeat the action for each row.

Comment: ah sorry - was looking at n for some reason. Why not loop through the range instead?